# Connect Microsoft Lifecam with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, camera, webcam

I am having trouble using the Microsoft Lifecam with Matlab. I have already installed all the drivers (including the USB webcams Package in Matlab) and the camera seems to work fine when I open it from its own app. However, when I open it from Matlab I get an error and I need to close Matlab.

This is the way I am doing it:

```
cam_List = webcamlist;
```

which returns the name of my laptop's camera and the Microsoft camera

```
cam = webcam(2);
```

This works fine with the laptop's camera `webcam(1)`.

The error I get is shown on the image
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aJjV.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running as admin, error appears to tell that "java is not allowed to access graphics driver"